# Google Cloud Machine Learning API Dot Net Client - Predict Request Failing

Tags: google-api, google-api-dotnet-client, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-ml-engine

I have a trained model (CNN) deployed in Google Cloud Platform, from which I'm able to get predictions using either the Python client library, or the `gcloud` command.

I am now trying to use the Dot Net client v1.25 (https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/tree/v1.25.0) to get predictions, but the request is failing with `{"error": "Missing "instances" field in request body."}` even though the JSON I'm sending is of the form:

```
   {"instances": [{"image":<base64ImageData>, "key":"1"}]}
```

I can use the library to get a list of available models using the `List()` method.

Code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using System.IO;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.CloudMachineLearningEngine.v1beta1.Data;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace GoogleCloudTesting
{
    Class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefaultAsync().Result;

            var service = new Google.Apis.CloudMachineLearningEngine.v1beta1.CloudMachineLearningEngineService(
                new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "Testing"
                }
            );

            string jsonImagesPath = @"c:\path\to\images.json"; // {"instances": [{"image":<base64imagedata>, "key":"1"}]}
            string json = File.ReadAllText(jsonImagesPath);

            var request = new GoogleCloudMlV1beta1PredictRequest
            {
                HttpBody = new GoogleApiHttpBody { Data = json }
            };

            var predictRequest = service.Projects.Predict(request, "projects/my_project/models/my_model/versions/V1");
            var result = predictRequest.Execute();
            Console.WriteLine(result.Data); // null
        }
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects/predict suggests base64 encoded data must be replaced by a JSON object with a single attribute named 'b64'. So perhaps you need to use: { "instances": [{"image": { "b64": "<base64>" }, "key": "1" } ] }

Comment: I see a subtle difference compared to the Python version (https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/how-tos/online-predict#requesting_predictions), but I don't know the .net library well enough to fix it with certainty. The difference is that HttpBody is not used in Python. Instead, something more like service.Projects.Predict(body=json, name="projects/my_project/models/my_model/versions/V1"). Again, I can't guarantee exactly that will work, but I'm pretty sure the problem is the HttpBody.

Comment: Please follow the instructions here: https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/faq.html#how-can-i-trace-requests-and-responses-in-rest-based-apis to dump the HTTP request headers and body.  Then, post the dump here.

Comment: @JeffreyRennie What looks to be happening is that the request object GoogleCloudMlV1beta1PredictRequest is being serialized, resulting in 
the request body: {"httpBody": {"data": <body> ...} instead of just the <body> I specify.
There is no other way to send a request apparently.

Comment: @Chris, I have the same problem... the property named "Data" is not a part of JSON structure of API Explorer... 
Do you have any solution?

Comment: @IbereSpadoto I had to change the method signature of `PredictRequest` from  `public PredictRequest(Google.Apis.Services.IClientService service, Google.Apis.CloudMachineLearningEngine.v1beta1.Data.GoogleCloudMlV1beta1PredictRequest body, string name) : base(service)` to             `public PredictRequest(Google.Apis.Services.IClientService service, object body, string name) : base(service)`
and also change the `Body` property in the `PredictRequest` class to type `object` in the file google.apis.cloudmachinelearningengine.v1beta1.cs.

Comment: So I've downloaded the sorce code too... I think about this way but, I can't run the source, I got a lot of errors in Visual Studio... 
Could you send this changes to me, please?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue.

Two work-arounds are shown in github [issue#1068](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1068)